# HTML body getting offset by jQuery, can't find cause/source in DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a site that uses a common set of code, everything works fine with the exception of 1 page where the `<body>` tag is being offset by 90px.

I can't for the life of me find out what is modifying the page - I'm assuming there is a way to track/view adjustments to the page as they happen?

I found the offset by using the following:

```
alert($("body").offset().top);
$(document).ready(function () { alert($("body").offset().top); });
```

The above code yields 0 with the first alert and 90 with the second alert.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Having some code to look at would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it happens because of the margin-top on a heading, try to remove every headings on the page that causes problem and if it fixes the problem, add `margin-top:0px` to your headings

Comment: Thanks @Xposedbones - In viewing my code, I don't have a margin-top set on the body. Are you suggesting that all elements be set to 0px?

Comment: no, when I have this problem is usually because one of the first tags in the body is a H1 with a margin-top. the body get pushed by the h1's margin-top.

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't seem to be a sub-element - as I mentioned, all other pages on the site work fine, just one page is having this problem. Almost like jQuery is making an adjustment prior to the completion of the page load.

Comment: Is there an url that I could see? If not, try disabling your javascript and see if the problem persist

Comment: It should only account for the default 8px, not the 90px in question.

Comment: You were right. Found a div that was inside the body that had 90px top margin. I have never seen that behavior before. Very odd that it did not happen on other pages as well as other pages have the 90px top margin on internal elements. Any idea why that supersedes and gives the body an offset?

Comment: Good to know :) To help others who have the same issue, can you mark my post as the answer?  Glad I could help